# The specified format name does not support the requested operation. For example, a direct queue format name cannot be deleted

Tags: system.messaging

I'm trying to send a message to a queue using a Message object and am getting the error

The specified format name does not support the requested operation. For example, a direct queue format name cannot be deleted.

Here is the code.

```
        Order ord = new Order(new Guid(), "Smith & Smith");

        Message orderMessage = new Message(ord);
        orderMessage.UseEncryption = true;
        orderMessage.EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithm.Rc2;
        orderMessage.Recoverable = true;
        orderMessage.Priority = MessagePriority.VeryHigh;
        orderMessage.TimeToBeReceived = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
        orderMessage.UseJournalQueue = true;
        orderMessage.Body = "Test Encryption";
        queue.Send(orderMessage, "Encrypted Order");
```

Any help with this is appreciated.

Tom

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever solve this? I came across this problem myself and found out I needed to use (just like the error says) a different format name.

The strange thing was that if I set UseAuthentication property using the MQ certificate, then it worked. But if I also wanted to set UseEncryption, then it did not work.

You do not specify your queue/server setup/formats, but I suspect you're trying to send from one machine to another machine's public queue within the same domain, using DIRECT formatname? As the MQ Manager will use the domain AD to lookup the certificate and queue details, it raises an exception as the format name is invalid (not the same as specified in the AD). So instead of using the direct format, use the queue ID to define the formatname. I switched this:

```
"FormatName:Direct=TCP:111.222.1.22\your_public_queue"
```

with this:

```
"FormatName:PUBLIC=7EB2A53C-7593-462C-A568-5A0EFA26D91D"
```

Now it worked. You can find your queue ID by right-clicking your queue on the receiver machine and then go to Properties->General and see the value specified in field "ID".

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. A pity, as it's a plausible workaround!

Comment: @Contango, what was the error after you changed it to use the public name?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that getting the FormatName correct whether public or private in nature will save hours of work.  It's incredibly important to understand the setup of each (Public requiring AD and private does not when access remotely).  This is a great summary of FormatName.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnbreakwell/2009/02/26/difference-between-path-name-and-format-name-when-accessing-msmq-queues/

Answer (score 0):

One note on this issue, if your queue format name starts this way: "FormatName:Direct=" then you will receive the error "The specified format name does not support the requested operation. For example, a direct queue format name cannot be deleted" if you try to access the queue's QueueName property. Use the queue's FormatName property instead.