# MSMQ complaining about format name while reading messages

Tags: vb.net, msmq

I have a non transacitonal private queue(errors) on a remote machine(10.3.35.3), running xp. I am trying to read messages from a machine which runs windows 2008.
I am using "FormatName:Direct=tcp:10.3.35.3\Private$\errors" to access the queue.

I can connect to it.
I can peek.
I have a eventHandler for ReceiveCompleted event, and it get fired once there is a message received from queue, however when I try to convert "source" object to messageQueue.

```
Friend Sub MyReceiveCompleted(ByVal [source] As [Object], ByVal asyncResult As   ReceiveCompletedEventArgs)
Dim objMessageQueue As MessageQueue
Try

    objMessageQueue = New MessageQueue
    objMessageQueue = CType([source], MessageQueue)
```

At this point when I try to convert "source" object to MessageQueue object I got  exception "The specified format name does not support the requested operation. For example, a direct queue format name cannot be deleted.".

full stack trace of exception

```
at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.GenerateQueueProperties()
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.get_QueuePath()
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.get_QueueName()
   at MyReceiveCompleted(Object source, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs asyncResult)
```

I have tried different format names, no luck. can anyone please explain what is wrong in here? is there any other format name I need to use? can we know what formatname a queue will like beforehand?

Note: in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174115/the-specified-format-name-does-not-support-the-requested-operation-for-example) someone said to use id instead, when I look for id in properties of queue I got all 0s in "Type ID:" field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I give up on this, it is still not working becuase it is part of a very messy old code. I created my own little application(using the same code, same .net framework) and it can connect to remote queues and read/write/peek. so I believe this was an example of maintenance nightmare of a very very old code base.

during my research I have found some useful links, which may help someone who lands here in future. John Breakwell has following to contribute about remote queue

[There is a new security in MSMQ4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/02/12/msmq-4-0-what-s-new-in-computer-management.aspx)

[A registry key in MSMQ3.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/01/15/msmq-3-0-too-secure-for-you.aspx)

[some ports info regarding msmq](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/04/29/clear-the-way-msmq-coming-through.aspx)

[some more info about remote msmq 4.0 processing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/07/10/getting-msmq-messages-out-of-windows-server-2008.aspx)

To see if your msmq is installed in workgroup mode or other one, goto HKLM->Software-> Microsoft->MSMQ->Parameters check REG_DWORD workgroup.
1 is workgroup mode.
0 is AD mode.

and if you want to know the version of your msmq, check version section of [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing)

I almost forgot to mention that as a rule of thumb I believe we should always read local and write remote, not other way round.