# Powershell delete MSMQ remotely

Tags: powershell, msmq

I was wondering if it was possible to delete queues remotely via PowerShell? I have the following script:

```
cls

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging")

$computers = @("comp1","comp2","comp3");

foreach($computer in $computers) {

    $messageQueues = [System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::GetPrivateQueuesByMachine($computer);

    foreach ($queue in $messageQueues) {
        $endpoint = [string]::Format("FormatName:DIRECT=OS:{0}\{1}", $computer, $queue.QueueName);

        Write-Host $endpoint
        [System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::Delete($endpoint);        
    }
}
```

This works fine, if I was running it on the machine whose queues I want to delete however when I run this remotely I get the error:

```
The specified format name does not support the requested operation. For example, a direct queue format name cannot be deleted.
```

Any ideas if this can be done?

*EDIT*

Oddly, I have figured I can remote onto the machine via PowerShell and execute a script block. However, I don't understand the difference between doing:

THIS:

```
$endpoint = [string]::Format("FormatName:DIRECT=OS:{0}\{1}", $computer, $queue.QueueName);
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock { [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging"); [System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::Delete($endpoint) };
```

AND THIS:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock { [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging"); [System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::Delete("FormatName:DIRECT=OS:MY_SERVER\some.endpoint") };
```

The value of `$endpoint` is the same however, for some odd reason it doesn't like the variable approach though both values are identical. I tested this by setting `$endpoint` then calling delete. I get the error:

```
Exception calling "Delete" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid value  for parameter path."
```

What I'm trying to say is if I hard code the value as part of the argument it works but assign it to a variable then invoke the method I get an error

Comment: Might want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174115/the-specified-format-name-does-not-support-the-requested-operation-for-example) out.  The error message may not be lying about the need for a different name format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For historic purposes if anyone else is experiencing this issue or is wondering how to delete queues remotely then please see below.

1. **How do I delete private queues on a remote computer?** It is possible to delete queues remotely. This can be achieved using the command `Enable-PSRemoting -Force`. Without this, you encounter the issue @JohnBreakWell indicated (see his link to MSDN).
2. **The scope of variables when using Invoke-Command?** The problem I found was the variables I declared were simply out of scope (script block was unable to see it). To rectify this, I simply did the following:

The important bit being the `argument list` and the use of `param`.

```
 $computers = @("comp1","comp2");

    foreach($computer in $computers) {
        [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging"); 

        $messageQueues = [System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::GetPrivateQueuesByMachine($computer);

        foreach ($queue in $messageQueues) {
            $endpoint = [string]::Format("FormatName:DIRECT=OS:{0}\{1}", $computer, $queue.QueueName);

            Enable-PSRemoting -Force
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
                param ($computer, $endpoint)
                [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging"); 
                [System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::Delete($endpoint) 
            }

        } -ArgumentList $computer, $endpoint

    }
```

Comment: This is great, I better agree with you with a name like that, you must be a pretty big lad

Comment: Yes I am but in a Dwayne Johnson kinda way

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete a remote private queue. 
You need to perform the operation locally to the queue.

From [MQDeleteQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms704038(v=vs.85).aspx):

**Remarks**
(2nd paragraph)
"Private queues registered on a remote computer ... cannot be deleted."

Comment: I am aware of the documentation :) which is why I opted to use PowerShell remote commands. Please refer to the updated post which I hope will shed some light on the matter. I able to delete private queues if I use Enable-PSRemoting

Comment: Apologies - I missed the actual question about why the two script blocks differ. 
Remoting works as you're then dealing with a local queue as far as the delete command is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

As Dr. Schizo mentioned, you'll need to execute

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
```

on the remote machine, but then, assuming you're using Server 2012 r2, it's as simple as:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTERNAME { Get-MsmqQueue -Name QUEUENAME | Remove-MsmqQueue }
```